# WPF to Silverlight threading conversion

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight-3.0

In WPF on .Net 4 i had a similar loop spawning background work:

```
        Point[] points = GetPoints();
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

        // loop bitmap
        for (int x = 0; x < bitmap.Width; x++) {
           for (int y = 0; y < bitmap.Height; y++) {
              Task t = new Task((object point) => {
                  Point p = points[((Point)point).Y * bitmap.Width + ((Point)point).X];
                  p.CalculateInterference(); // a bit slow
              }, new Point(x, y));
              t.Start();
              tasks.Add(t);
           }
           // after spawning tasks for all the Y column I need them to finish before proceeding
           foreach (var t in tasks) {
             t.Wait();
           }
           tasks.Clear();
        }
```

This was easy with the Task class in .NET4, but on Silverlight 3 I don't see them...

What would be the easiest but still correct way to make this work in Silverlight without spawning Y threads in parallel, because Y can be a large value. It would be good it it uses the available CPU resources of the host...

Thanks!

Comment: ThreadPool? You'd have to do a lot of the work yourself though.

Comment: Maybe the ThreadPool but how to use it correctly with this construct, I need them all finished after the inner loop. If I queued all of them and do Thread.Join on a thread that is not yet scheduled soon to be run in the Pool I would basically block until it gets run and kill all the performance gain of parallelism? or am I mistaken?

Comment: That would sure be a lot of work, that's why I didn't post this as 'answer' ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the .NET4 version you would be better off using `Parallel.For`:

- [Parallel.For Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for.aspx)

It is exactly for this kind of situation.

For Silverlight you can grow your own and here is some code to get you started:

- [9 Reusable Parallel Data Structures and Algorithms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163427.aspx)

See the section entitled **Loop Tiling**.

Comment: great tips, I'll have a look at the second link.